# Can I increase maximum number of column in MySQL innoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need 4000 columns in one InnoDB table.
InnoDB allows 1017 columns.
Can I increase this number? How?
I want to save 4000 timeseries in one table.
See table [timeseries table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNVtP.jpg) 
Evry column saves one timeseries.
Column name is other tables auto incremented value. Other tables holds timeseries name and optional datas.

Comment: Suggesting to use multiple number of tables referencing with the primary ID to a main table, and returning the rows with JOIN

Comment: Do you *really* need that many columns? Why? There is no way to go vertical?

Comment: Can you expand your question a little bit with information about *why* you need 4000 columns, to avoid an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/145161)?

Comment: It just seems immensely unlikely that a well designed database would require this many columns

Comment: 4k columns is a good indicator you've done something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Straight answer:  No.

What to do instead:

If you are splaying an array of values across columns, don't.  Make another table with a 2-part `PRIMARY KEY` -- the PK of your table, plus which array element it is.

If you have lots of optional columns, serialize them into a JSON string and put it into a single column.  Keep the non-optional columns as real columns.

If it is some other pattern please explain.

There are multiple reasons for having a limit on the number of columns, one reason it "bad schema design".