# how to set MYSQL CONCAT MAX LENGTH

Tags: mysql, concatenation

i have select concat on my Store procedure like this

```
SET @resultQuery = CONCAT("
SELECT
    @no := @no + 1 AS no,
    uniqueCode,
    orderNumber,
    orderDate,
    orderTime,
    salesName,
    buyerCategory,
    discountCode,
    buyerName,
    email,
    mobile,
    module,
    module_id,
    productsNumber,
    purchaseValue,
    postalFee,
    discount,
    premium,
    uniqueCode2,
    total,
    ", @productsSelect, "
FROM
    (SELECT 
            @uniqueCode := IFNULL(om.id, 0) AS uniqueCode,
            @orderNumber := IFNULL(om.code_order, '') AS orderNumber,
            IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(om.createdAt, '%e/%c/%Y'), '') AS orderDate,
            IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(om.createdAt, '%H:%i'), '') AS orderTime,
            IFNULL(sls.fullname, '') AS salesName,
            IFNULL((CASE
                            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT
                                                ob.buyer_id
                                            FROM
                                                order_match om2
                                                    LEFT JOIN
                                                order_buyer ob2 ON om2.order_buyer_id = ob2.id
                                            WHERE
                                                om2.createdAt < ?
                                                    AND om2.order_status_id IN (4, 5, 6, 8)
                                                    AND ob.buyer_id = ob2.buyer_id
                                            GROUP BY ob2.buyer_id)
                                THEN 'Ulang'
                            ELSE 'Baru'
                        END), '') AS buyerCategory,
            IFNULL(odis.discount_code, '') AS discountCode,
            IFNULL(usr.fullname, '') AS buyerName,
            IFNULL(usr.email, '') AS email,
            IFNULL(usr.mobile, '') AS mobile,
            mdl.name AS module,
            mdl.id AS module_id,
            @i AS productsNumber,
            ", @products, "
            @purchaseValue := IFNULL(om.total_price, 0) AS purchaseValue,
            @postalFee := IFNULL(od.price, 0) AS postalFee,
            @discount := IFNULL((SELECT
                                    CASE
                                        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 
                                                            rdh.debit
                                                        FROM 
                                                            referral_deposit_histories rdh
                                                        WHERE
                                                            rdh.order_match_id = om2.id
                                                                AND
                                                            rdh.debit > 0)
                                            THEN (SELECT 
                                                        rdh.debit
                                                    FROM 
                                                        referral_deposit_histories rdh
                                                    WHERE
                                                        rdh.order_match_id = om2.id
                                                            AND
                                                        rdh.debit > 0)
                                        ELSE (SELECT
                                                    odis2.discount_amount
                                                FROM
                                                    order_discount odis2
                                                WHERE
                                                    odis2.order_match_id = om2.id)
                                    END
                                FROM
                                    order_match om2
                                WHERE
                                    om2.id = om.id), 0) AS discount,
            @premium := IFNULL(op.price, 0) AS premium,
            @uniqueCode2 := IFNULL(CASE
                                        WHEN om.createdAt > '2017-08-02 23:59:59'
                                            THEN pmh.price
                                        ELSE @uniqueCode
                                    END, 0) AS uniqueCode2,
            @total := IFNULL(@purchaseValue + @postalFee - @discount + @premium + @uniqueCode2, 0) AS total
        FROM
            order_match om
                LEFT JOIN
            order_discount odis ON om.id = odis.order_match_id
                LEFT JOIN
            discount_sales ds ON odis.discount_code = ds.discount_code
                LEFT JOIN
            sales sls ON ds.sales_id = sls.id
                LEFT JOIN
            order_buyer ob ON om.order_buyer_id = ob.id
                LEFT JOIN
            users usr ON ob.buyer_id = usr.id
                LEFT JOIN
            order_delivery od ON om.id = od.order_match_id
                LEFT JOIN
            order_premium op ON om.id = op.order_match_id
                LEFT JOIN
            payment_method_history pmh ON om.id = pmh.order_match_id
                LEFT JOIN
            modules mdl ON om.module_id = mdl.id
        WHERE
            om.createdAt >= ?
                AND om.createdAt <= ?
                AND om.order_status_id IN (4, 5, 6, 8)
        ORDER BY om.createdAt DESC) paidOrdersTable");

PREPARE stmt FROM @resultQuery;
SET @paramDateFrom = paramDateFrom;
SET @paramDateTo = paramDateTo;
EXECUTE stmt USING @paramDateFrom, @paramDateFrom, @paramDateTo;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

and it return `Error Code: 1117. Too many columns`

how to setting the maximum length for concat, what i learn on another platform, its set group_concat_max_len, but since it's not group concat (because it's concat not group_concat), what should i take for solve this problem? i need some code like set group_concat_max_len but for concat not group_concat

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from the `CONCAT()` syntax? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=a1d8d531a81e3bbf7c869ec5ea3a8d16

Comment: actually, since the queries refer to prepare stmt from resultQuery, i thought it will be a focus on that concat, but actually, there's another code before resultQuery which refer to resultQuery, should i mention it too since the problem is not from the concat?

Comment: If you include the query before `resultQuery` you mentioned but if its not the one making the error, its useless. You have to find out which query making the error first. Run your queries one by one and then you can refer to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3972/error-code-1117-too-many-columns-mysql-column-limit-on-table/3976) . Honestly, I think if you really need all the columns, there's no other choice but to increase the limit.

Comment: ya,  i think i need to increase the limit for the concat resultQuery, do you know how to do that?

Comment: I think the limit is imposed on how many columns in the `SELECT ..` and not the `CONCAT`. Have you found which query that creates the error? If yes, how many columns is in the `SELECT .. `? If I look at your query in the question, both of the sub-query and outer-query have less than 25 columns so I don't think it's coming from there. Also, did you refer to the link I posted in my previous comment?

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a mistake with suggesting to increase the limit because after looking around, it seems like there's [no way to increase the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006007/can-i-increase-maximum-number-of-column-in-mysql-innodb).